# cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘int&&’ to lvalue of type ‘int’ in perfect forwarding

Tags: c++, rvalue, lvalue

I'm writing a delegate for class method. Sample code below:

```
template <typename T> class Delegate;

template<typename R, typename ...Args>
class Delegate<R(Args...)> final {
public:
  Delegate(const Delegate& rhs) : obj_(rhs.obj_), stub_(rhs.stub_) {}

  template <class T, R(T::*TMethod)(Args...)>
  static Delegate create(T* instance) {
    return Delegate(instance, method_stub<T, TMethod>);
  } //create

  template <typename ...B>
  R operator()(B &&... args) const {
    return (*stub_)(obj_, std::forward<B>(args)...);
  } //operator()

private:
  using stub_t = R(*)(void*, Args&&...);
  void* obj_ = nullptr;
  stub_t stub_ = nullptr;

  Delegate(void* obj, stub_t stub) : obj_(obj), stub_(stub) {
  } //delegate

  template <class T, R(T::*TMethod)(Args...)>
  static R method_stub(void* obj, Args &&... args) {
    T* p = static_cast<T*>(obj);
    return (p->*TMethod)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  } //method_stub
};

class Sample {
  long m;
public:
  double A(int) { 
    std::cout << "Sample::A" << std::endl;
    return 0.1; 
  }
}; //class Sample

int main() {
  Sample sample;
  Delegate<double(int)> myfunc = Delegate<double(int)>::create<Sample, &Sample::A>(&sample);
  int k = 9;
  myfunc(k);
}
```

However, the above code won't compile, complaining the line in `R operator()(B &&... args) const` when compiling the the last line in the main function.

**error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘int&&’ to lvalue of type ‘int’**

Since I declare function call operator as template member function, and use `std::forward` to forward the params, why I'm stilling seeing the error above?

Comment: `Delegate` is istantiated with `double(int)` which means `stub_t = double (*)(void*, int&&)` and you are trying to pass it an lvalue. Which the error message tells you already... so what is unclear?

Comment: `Args` is a class template parameter, so writing `Args&&` is not a forwarding reference , it's an rvalue reference (at least in this case) if that's of any help.

Comment: @super yes, I just realized that the way I write it, ```Args``` is already defined as the template parameter in Delegate, so I really should declare ```using stub_t = R(*)(void*, Args...)```, or I forced the parameters passed in to the function call operator to be right reference. If I use ```std::forward<Args>(args)``` in function call operator and ```method_stub```, I will be able to keep the value type and reference type of the parameters passed in, right?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean. There is probably an easier way to do what you're trying to do. From your example it's not clear what exactly you need more then `auto myfunc = [&](int i) { return sample.A(i); };`. Why is there a `void*` involved? What's the idea behind `Delegate`?